# WCHAR * and auto WCHAR and how they allocate memory

Tags: c++

I thought if I used `calloc()` to allocate memory that it would use memory in the OS, but it doesn't because the In Use Memory in the OS (and the process it's called from) don't change. However, if I use `auto...make_unique()`, it *does* consume memory for the active process it's called from.

Can someone clarify for me (1) the difference between the memory allocations and (2) does it even matter in the process how I allocate memory (besides the fact if I don't `free()` it after using it)?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
wchar_t *asdf = (wchar_t*)calloc(10240000000, sizeof(wchar_t));

wchar_t *asdf2 = new WCHAR[10240000000]();

getchar();

auto dBuffer = std::make_unique <wchar_t[]>(640000000);  // 32-bit process can't use more than this

std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

getchar();
}
```

Comment: Why is `calloc()` showing up in allegedly C++ code?

Comment: A) Why not [`std::wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? B) Why not `std::vector<wchar_t>`? C) If not that, why not `new`?

Comment: When you allocate memory, always you allocate memory for the process you're running in. It is never an allocation in another process, or the "OS", whatever that means. The OS attributes all user-space allocations to a process.

Comment: Also not sure what that "32-bit process" remark is about. A 32-bit process can use up to 4GB of memory, but the system itself can have a lot more than that, even on 32-bit hardware.

Comment: You never check whether `calloc` actually allocates anything. `10240000000` looks like it will overflow on 32-bit system. You need to use memory profiler to track memory [de]allocations.

Comment: C26400 says `The idea is that you should clearly state ownership of memory resources.` <- That's where I'm confused when I've used `new` vs. `auto`.

Comment: At very least check the return value of `calloc` if it is a null pointer; if so, allocation failed.

Comment: *'`new` vs. `auto`'* – there's no versus, they are orthogonal concepts. `auto` is used for automatically deducing a type while `new` is used to create dynamically allocated objects or arrays of.

Comment: 10'240'000'000 x 2 or 4 is a _lot_ of memory. You _must_ check if `calloc` succeeds.

Comment: If I allocate with `auto` like C26400 suggests, then I can't do `StringCchCopyW(dBuffer, 32, L"Hello, world.");`

Comment: @JeffR `auto` makes the pointer deduce to `gsl::owner< wchar_t >`, which you should be able to pass to `StringCchCopyW`

Comment: Yet an issue, though unrelated: You shouldn't use C-style casts in C++ code, use the C++ `xyz_cast<type>()` variants instead (here a `static_cast` is fine).

Comment: @MooingDuck `StringCchCopyW` gives an error of "no suitable conversion function from 'std::unique_ptr<WCHAR [], std::default_delete<WCHAR []>>' to STRSAFE_LPWSTR exists" and 'cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<WCHAR [],std::default_delete<WCHAR []>>' to 'STRSAFE_LPWSTR'

Comment: @MooingDuck That's not even enabled: [`template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>> using owner = T;`](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/pointers) – and there's no reason to confuse the question author even more by 'complicated' (well, not for us…) aliases  if `auto` can be simply deduced to `wchar_t*`.

Comment: I have to use a `.get()` to store the value. Odd, because it appears `auto` is assuming it's a vector?

Comment: @JeffR - As an aside, `WCHAR` was a macro introduced by Microsoft for compilers that didn't support `wchar_t`. No reason to use that since the 1900's ended.

Comment: @TedLyngmo (user7860670, aconcagua) The reason calloc wasn't consuming any memory was it was *failing*. So basic it's embarrassing!